# creating a temp file using(FileStream) results in "The process cannot access the file because it is being used"

Tags: c#, filestream, temporary-files

I'm reading a file from a SQL server and writing it to disk temporarily so that another program can access it.  Pretty easy with Path.GetTempFileName().

My problem is that I need these temp files deleted once the process has been completed.  I'm doing this with the FileStream class, such as:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write,    FileShare.None, 8, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose))
{  
  //code here ultimately accessing the temp file
}
```

With the fileOptions set, the file is deleted once the *using* is finished and FileStream is disposed.  The file is definitely creating and deleting on cue, but any process accessing the file responds with *"The process cannot access the file because it is being used..."*

Understandable if my FileStream still has access to the file (I've tried modifying the FileShare without success; this other process is not a filestream.)

I'm hoping to avoid using delete methods (which will require more error trapping).  Is there a simple way to (utilizing the FileStream) create my temp file and remove it once the other process is complete?

Comment: Just to confirm, if you use FileShare.ReadWrite, you still have the problem?

Comment: Confirmed.  file still in use (other process is not a FileStream).

Comment: Do you have any control over the other application? How will you know when the file has been read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a possibility here with the using statement, but you can use the `Process.WaitForExit()` method to wait for the other process to end, after which you can safely delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you running on the Windows OS, DeleteOnClose is actually backed up by the **FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE** flags passed to the [CreateFile Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Documentation says: "*The file is to be deleted immediately after all of its handles are closed, which includes the specified handle and any other open or duplicated handles*."

So you need to call **DuplicateHandle** (doc [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724251%28VS.85%29.aspx)) on FileStream's Handle or SafeFileHandle property. You should be able to do this in the using. Here is one possibility of DuplicateHandle declaration in C#:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool DuplicateHandle(
    IntPtr hSourceProcess,
    SafeFileHandle hSourceHandle,
    IntPtr hTargetProcessHandle,
    out IntPtr hTargetHandle,
    uint dwDesiredAccess,
    bool fInheritHandle,
    uint dwOptions);
```

I have not tested this, but It has good chances to work :-)

Answer (score -1):

Close th fileStream using Close() method of the stream before the closing of using clause.

Comment: this doesn't change anything, as `Close` is called at the end of the using anyway. You'd have to relinquish the exclusive access to the file for the other process to read it, thus closing the using anyway.

Comment: Yeah, tried that too. As the fileStream is set with FileOptions.DeleteOnClose, Close() removes the file before its time.